# Python 3.6.9 - Lists - In-place modification in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background**:

I have a list of names and email addresses stored in a Python list.

```
user_data_list = [['Adam', 'adam@abc.com'],
                  ['Alice', 'alice@stu.edu'],
                  ['Eve', 'eve@abc.com'],
                  ['Bob', 'bob@abc.com']]
```

I have two lists containing the old and the updated email addresses, `old_domain_email_list` and `new_domain_email_list`, respectively. The contents of the lists are:

```
old_domain_email_list = ['adam@abc.com', 'eve@abc.com', 'bob@abc.com']
new_domain_email_list = ['adam@xyz.com', 'eve@xyz.com', 'bob@xyz.com']
```

I intend to update the email addresses to now contain `xyz.com` instead of `abc.com`. The below lines of code iterates through the `user_data_list` and updates the matched entries in the list.

```
for user in user_data_list:
    for old_domain_email, new_domain_email in zip(old_domain_email_list, new_domain_email_list):
        if user[1] == old_domain_email:
            user[1] = new_domain_email
```

The changed `name` and `email address` pairs are then written to a CSV file.

```
with open(report_file_location, 'w+') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        writer.writerows(user_data_list)
        output_file.close()
```

**Query**:

Are the user details in the `user_data_list` updated by the line `user[1] = ' ' + new_domain_email` happening *in-place*? The code doesn't *explicitly* tries to modify the `user_data_list`, but still, the `writer.writerows(user_data_list)` method correctly creates the new file with the updated domain names.

Python version used: 3.6.9

I hope I am able to make the question clear.

Comment: Yes, indexed assignment *always* modifies the object in-place. You didn't modify the outer list, though, but you did modify the list that is referenced by the outer list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Did you mean the indexed assignment in the expression `user[1] = new_domain_email`? Is this behavior exhibited by all iterator objects in Python?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `user` is referring to a *list object*, not an iterator object (the iterator object is created underneath the hood and used implicitly in a for-loop). But indexed-assignment `user[1] = new_domain_email` **always** modifies the list object `user`. Of course, user-defined classes can implement indexed-assignment to *not* work that way, but all built-in containers have those semantics (so, `list` and `dict`)

Comment: `...exhibited by all iterator objects...` - Some [Iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) don't support [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?#subscriptions) or item assignment - for instance a generator expression - `a = (foo for foo in [1,2,3,4])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the modification is happening in place.  `user[i] = ...` invokes `user`'s `__setitem__` method which does not change the object to which the `user` reference points.

Comment: To be pedantic, `list.__setitem__` *happens* to work in-place. But yes.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can simplify the email address replacement using list comprehension.

```
[[i[0], i[1].split('@')[0]+'@xyz.com'] for i in user_data_list]
```

result:

```
[['Adam', 'adam@xyz.com'], ['Alice', 'alice@xyz.com'], ['Eve', 'eve@xyz.com'], ['Bob', 'bob@xyz.com']]
```